# A problem about Lebesgue-measurability, irrational numbers, and rational numbers.

Tags: lebesgue-measure, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Recently, I am reading the book [1]. Theorem 1.6.1 in [1] is as follows:

> ***Theorem 1.6.1*** *There exists a set on the real line that is not Lebesgue-measurable*.
>
> *Proof*. Denote by $\xi$ any irrational number and also the number 0. Denote by $R$ a sequence $\{ r_n \}$ of all the rational numbers. Finally, denote by $E_\xi$ the set $\{ \xi + r; r \in R \}$. Clearly $E_{\xi_1} \cap E_{\xi_2} = \emptyset$ if $E_{\xi_1} \neq E_{\xi_2}$. ...

I try to prove the following claim by myself:

***Claim***: $E_{\xi_1} \cap E_{\xi_2} = \emptyset$ if $E_{\xi_1} \neq E_{\xi_2}$.

*Proof*. I try to use the **proof by contradiction** to prove the above claim. Suppose that $E_{\xi_1} \cap E_{\xi_2} \neq \emptyset$. Then there exists an element $a$ such that $a \in E_{\xi_1} \cap E_{\xi_2}$. Therefore, $a$ can be written as
$$ a = \xi_1 + r_1 = \xi_2 + r_2, \tag{1}$$
where $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ are irrational numbers or 0 and $r_1$ and $r_2$ are rational numbers. From (1) we have
$$ \xi_1 - \xi_2 = r_2 - r_1. \tag{2} $$
Because $E_{\xi_1} \neq E_{\xi_2}$, $\xi_1 \neq \xi_2$. Because if $\xi_1 = \xi_2$, then $E_{\xi_1} = E_{\xi_2}$. $\xi_1 - \xi_2$ could be an irrational number or a rational number. $r_2 - r_1$ must be a rational number. I cannot derive a contradiction.

Do you know how to prove the claim? Thank you in advance.

**References**

[1] A. Friedman, *Foundations of Modern Analysis*, Dover Publications. Inc., 1982.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Because $\xi_1 - \xi_2 = r_2 - r_1 $ and $r_1, r_2$ are rational, it follows that $\xi_1 - \xi_2$ must be rational. This means that $\xi_1 = q+ \xi_2$ for some rational $q$. Thus, $\xi_1 \in E_{\xi_2}$ and analogous $\xi_2 \in E_{\xi_1}$. This already shows that both sets are equal.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read your answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

$r_1$ and $r_2$ rational so their difference is rational. Hence $\xi_1-\xi_2 =r_2-r_1$ is rational. Now prove that $E_{\xi_1}=E_{\xi_2}$ by proving that each side is contained in the other. For example if $x$ belongs to the left side then $x=\xi_1+r$ for some rational number $r$. But then  $x=\xi_2+r_2-r_1+r$ which proves that $x$ belongs to  the right side (since $r_2-r_1+r$  is a rational number).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read your answer. :-)